# Why aren't my commits appearing in GitHub?

Tags: github, repository, tortoisegit

After 5 hours of troubleshooting, searching solutions and tutorials I can't help myself as to use you guys as a last hope before giving up.

I want to have a repo on github.com for a new project. So I created an account and a repo. So far, so good.

I installed Git and TortoiseGit and made a clone of my repo via HTTPS. Now, if I try to commit Tortoise tells me that it was successful but I do not see the changes on github.com.

I tried to clone via SSH. But here Tortoise gives me the error when I try to clone the repo:

> git did not exit cleanly (exit code 128)

I also tried to make a fork "trunk" from "master", but as in point 1 I can get trunk to my PC but I cannot commit.

So, hence the programs are well tested and running well, I must be the failure.

What must I know about Git to work with my repo on github.com?

What shall I do to get my changes committed?

Comment: You did not mention `git push`.  To push changes from local repository to a remote a push is required.

Comment: Why do the simplest things make the most annoying problems? It worked. I used TortoiseSVN before and commit was enough there. Now I only must tell Tortoise not to ask for connection data. Thanks a lot :D You made a guy happy

Comment: For learning how to use Git, I highly recommend the [free online Pro Git book](http://git-scm.com/book), particularly chapters 1-3 and 6-6.5. Learn how to rebase, both interactively and non-interactively.

Comment: Have downloaded it some minutes ago before checking here again. Wish I have found it earlier. Would have saved much time and nerves :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cforbish already found your problem: git push.

I thought perhaps some more explanation would help:

Keep in mind the reason you have the extra step is because Git is a distributed VCS, which means you don't just have a local copy of your files, but also a local copy of the entire repository (all revisions, tags, etc.).

So when you 'commit' you've committed those changes to your local copy of the repository, but not to github or any other 'remote' repository.

You can then follow up with a push to push the commit to one or more remote repositories. However, it isn't necessary to do so after every commit. I tend to do several small commits that are parts of implementing a particular feature or fix and when I'm done and satisfied that it is working, I will push all of those commits at once.

Similarly, you can use 'git pull' to retrieve commits from a remote repository that aren't in your local repository.