# File will not sync after committing in GitHub Windows client?

Tags: windows, git, github, repository

Some of my files will not sync to my Github account after numerous attempts to commit and then sync. I don't get an error message, but the files never show up on my account after clicking on "sync".

**Screenshots:**

[image: Github Remote Screen]

[image: Github Local Screen]

Comment: I decided to try out TortoiseHg with Bitbucket. So far so good.

Comment: In order for us to be able to answer this question, you would have needed to provide far more details about what steps you took and what commands you were trying to use in order to do what you were trying to do. Also, I don't recommend GitHub for Windows, out of all the Git GUIs I have ever tried, it is one of the worst, in my opinion. I actually don't recommend GUI usage for Git at all, actually, but if you insist on GUI usage, then I would recommend TortoiseGit or SourceTree for Windows users.

Comment: @KenShoufer: Is the nature of your problem similar to this one?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17878845/why-arent-my-commits-appearing-in-github

Comment: @Cupcake: I'm finding that while I like TortoiseGit on the windows platform, what is working best for me is Git Bash for Windows. I still have TortoiseGit installed and occasionally use it, but mostly use Git Bash.

Comment: @lain same here, I use msysgit Bash almost exclusively. That's why I stated in my earlier comment, I don't recommend using GUIs for the majority of tasks with Git.

Comment: @lian The Stack Overflow problem you mentioned is not quite the same as mine. The GitHub for Windows software seems buggy. It works some of the time and not others. I found a good tutorial on TortoiseHg and I'm having good success with it. Thanks for the advice. [Tutorial on ToroiseHg](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wqU9MFplgrQ)

Answer (score 8):

The easiest way to debug that kind of behaviour is to open a shell directly from GitHub for Windows:

[image: shell]

You can then check the result of:

```
git status
git add -A 
git commit -m "new commit"
git push
```