# How to restore tracking a repository

Tags: github-for-windows

I used "Clone in Desktop" on GitHub repository, which created the clone (using GitHub for Windows application) on my local drive.

Later I accidentally clicked on "Stop tracking this repo" in the GitHub application. How can I restore the tracking back? Now there is only option to "Clone" which fails because the directory exists and is not empty (I have some changes in the code so I would like to avoid backing up the code and merging it if there was easier option.)

**EDIT**
I also tracked the original repository and my clone was locally stored in subfolder of the default repository folder. That's why the "Clone" option failed. Fixed with "Clone to" and selecting the right folder with my clone.
(I tested with another repo cloned to default folder that after "Stop tracking this repo" and then clicking on Clone, the repo is tracked again.)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest option is to [open a shell from the GitHub for Windows GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18041375/6309), and type:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/user/repo
```

Comment: I tried but got "fatal: remote origin already exists.". I figured out GitHub for Windows does not modify remotes, it only removes the repository from its internal list (stored in local database).