# Syncing commits from GitHub client (error updating submodules)

Tags: git, github

I created a new repository on GitHub and created a clone in my Home folder. I copied the programs I wanted to upload to GitHub and from this folder in terminal I entered:

```
git add .
git commit -m "Adding projects"
```

Then from the GitHub client application, I went to this repository and clicked sync for this unsynced commit.

I then get this error message:

```
Error updating submodules. You may not have permission to use the repositories. Go to GitHub > Preferences to make sure you're logged in.
```

I am logged in, and have searched in vain for an answer. My only suspicion is that it has something to do with how I used to use a different github account and that I do not have the correct RSA key in my ~/.ssh/ folder, but I am very inexperienced with git and would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Try and fall back to the command-line, [opening a shell from your GitHub client](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18041375/6309):

```
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

You will at least see a more descriptive error message.